# "Opening"/Divinding an HTML paragraph

Tags: javascript, css, html

This question could be an interesting problem to solve… 
On a web page that displays a text, I need a specific behavior : when the user clicks on some special words, an explanation of this word opens just below the clicked word. All the problem is : it should really open below the words, like "opening" the paragraph in two, without making the text that follows to jump to the next line.

**I found a solution** that works pretty well, using the CSS float property. 
You can see it there (would speak more than the code below) : http://jsfiddle.net/3gwzx/3/

The main problem of this solution, is that it uses nested span. And, as span aren't block tags, the padding wouldn't work with them. So, inside the gray box, **the text will never have any horizontal padding** (vertical padding is ok) - otherwise it changes the size of the box itself - or did I missed something ? - And that's bad. Has anybody got a solution ? Should I rethink the problem in a whole other way ?

Thanks you very, very much !

*Here is what the HTML looks like :*

```
<body onload="putListeners()">

<p>This is the normal text here, you cannot click it. But some words needs long
explanations, like this one : <span class="note">click on me

    <span class="noteTxt">The explanation begins here <a class="foo" href="bar.html"> and
    could have link</a> that one should be able to click. 
    And the note can be loooong, long, long, very, very long.
    </span>
  </span> 

And here, the text carry on. It could carry on for a long, long time.
And with all the other solutions I tried, this part of the text "jumps" after the note,
on a new line, when it appears. What I like here is that, when you open the note, 
it really "open the paragraphs in two". But i cannot give a padding
to those nested span… I should have a div… but you cannot put a div 
inside a span !</p>

</body>
```

*Here is the JS*

```
function putListeners() {

    //just listens to the text…
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("note");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       elements[i].addEventListener("click", showNote, false);
    }

};

function showNote()
{
    //content to show
    var currentTxt;

    //finds the nested noteTxt
    for (var i = 0; i < this.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (this.childNodes[i].className == "noteTxt") {
          currentTxt = this.childNodes[i];
         break;
      }        
    }

    //displays it or hides it
    if(currentTxt.style.display=="none" || currentTxt.style.display=="")
        {

            currentTxt.style.display="block";

        }
        else
        {
            currentTxt.style.display="none";
        }

     return true;
};
```

*And, for information, the relevant part of the CSS (you probably figured out what it looks like - complete code in the Jfiddle) :*

```
span.note {
    position: static;
}

span.note span.noteTxt {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

Comment: previousTxt is not defined

Comment: Why on Earth would you use JavaScript for this, when CSS could do it just as easily? Well, if `:hover` could be used, rather than having to be a click-event.

Comment: I like the question better than many answers I have read :) That said I don't understand your problem: You did set display: block for the span so it's now a block-element. And it has padding if you set it in the css: http://jsfiddle.net/3gwzx/4/ So where did I get you wrong?

Comment: Completely off topic, but is your other question, about the links in the spans not being clickable, solved now? I mean, I was in the process of answering it, but things got in the way and when I came back, it was deleted. So did you delete it because you found the answer, or had you given up on it?

Comment: @MrLister the comments showed me that my question was not very clear, and that the parts of code I give where not very "clean". So, rather than making people lose their time on that, I choosed to delete the question, and to look by myself.
But it's still not resolved ;)

Comment: Of course they complain about every example that contains more than the bare minimum needed to show the issue. But the problem was straightforward (the `noteText` was floating, so it ran into the margin area of the next paragraph, which was positioned and therefore higher up in the stacking order; with a non-transparent background it'd have hidden the span) and so was the solution (add `display:relative; z-index:1` to the style for the `span.noteTxt`.) If you hadn't put all that unnecessary "First line", "Second line" stuff in the fiddle, people would have seen that much earlier. Oh well.

Comment: Well… what can I say ? THANKS a lot. Next I will be a bit more patient before deleting a post…
And make better posts too ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the layout behavior of a tag, in your case `<span>` you can set css property `display: block` to change it to a div style layout.

```
span.asblock {
   display: block;
}
```

this will give you a span that behaves like a div.

Comment: God, I can't believe I didn't think about that. I'm so sorry, definitely, I tested everything but that…
David, alas, it must absolutly be a click event ! Otherwise, yes, I would have love to use only css. 
Thanks a lot for liking my question, Scheintod ;)

Comment: @user1229160 its totally okay, we all have days :)

Comment: @DonRamiro There are ways to do (more or less) what you want without click events, using only CSS. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/b4QtZ/) that shows three ways: one with a click to make the extra info visible, one that reacts to the mouse button being held down, and for completeness, one with hover.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks a lot ! That's very interesting. But could you manage to close the comment on a new click ? Other problem, that CSS cannot - I imagine ? - deal with : if the user click on another of those extra infos, the previous one must close. For my question, I removed the bit of code that manage that, but that's an extra feature that I need. 
Anyway, it's very interesting to learn that you can manage clicks with CSS. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @DonRamiro That's why I said "more or less"... There is a new HTML5 element called `<details>` that does what you want, without Javascript, but it's only supported in Chrome for now, so you'll have to wait a bit before using it in production. See http://html5doctor.com/the-details-and-summary-elements/

Comment: @MrLister Wow ! That's great to know ! Hope that others browser will use them soon, because that would be great… as long as it's customizable enough…